# Table with dummy row (ID 0) and auto increment index

Tags: combobox, auto-increment

Is it legal/okay to create a row with ID '0' and AFTER that set auto increment of that ID column to (1, 1)?

Why do I ask this?
I have a table `Products` with columns `ID` and `Name`. I want to show all `Products` inside my application in a ComboBox. Users can select a product but the default entry should not be 'Product 1' but something like '(Nothing selected)'. Is it okay to create a 'dummy row' with 'ID = 0' and Name = '(Nothing selected)' in database so the application will automatically display it as default selected item?

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is to programmatically add a please select option and validate against it, assuming you don't really want users to have this selected? I guess in theory what you've proposed should be OK though? You'd have to be careful retrieving the values in order of their Id though, if you ordered them by name you'd have to ensure you pulled Id = 0 first then ordered the rest which feels like more work then programmatically adding the option where needed to me.

If your users can have nothing selected then programmatically add the nothing selected option and handle saving no value if it is selected. Otherwise you're saving data that represents no data really which could be deemed a waste of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed it's working fine, I just wanted to see how other people think this should be solved. What you suggest is the cleaner solution but you have to write less event code if you already have a "dummy" item with id 0.